# Warning: TSD slot 10 retrieved but the thread data has already been torn down

Tags: iphone, ios

I did not find anything about this error... any idea where this comes from?

```
Warning: TSD slot 10 retrieved but the thread data has already been torn down.
Warning: TSD slot 10 set but the thread data has already been torn down.
```

Not sure how to debug this error. Don't exactly know where the warning occurs.

I found this in CFPlatform.c

```
// For the use of CF and Foundation only
CF_EXPORT void *_CFGetTSD(uint32_t slot) {
    if (slot > CF_TSD_MAX_SLOTS) {
        _CFLogSimple(kCFLogLevelError, "Error: TSD slot %d out of range (get)", slot);
        HALT;
    }
    __CFTSDTable *table = __CFTSDGetTable();
    if (!table) {
        // Someone is getting TSD during thread destruction. The table is gone, so we can't get any data anymore.
        _CFLogSimple(kCFLogLevelWarning, "Warning: TSD slot %d retrieved but the thread data has already been torn down.", slot);
        return NULL;
    }
    uintptr_t *slots = (uintptr_t *)(table->data);
    return (void *)slots[slot];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer has been discussed here
https://devforums.apple.com/message/596383#596383

Looks like UI Modification are tried to be done in a different thread.